# blocked due to MIME type (“application/octet-stream”) mismatch

Tags: theming

I've been troubleshooting a memcache issue on our Drupal 7 site and in the process the front end CSS broke, meaning all content was unstyled.

The Chrome console has a message:

> The resource from “/sites/all/themes/mbm/css/style.scss?qktcrf” was
> blocked due to MIME type (“application/octet-stream”) mismatch
> (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff).

Should Drupal be using a `.scss` file on the front end?

If not, how would I determine where the breakdown of the `.scss` being converted to a `.css` file occurs?

Help appreciated.
Steve

Comment: Normally the `scss` file is compiled into CSS as part of the build process. How that's done will depend on your project setup. Have a look into compiling SASS for more examples.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure that the scss files should be in a scss folder, and not the css folder.

```
/sites/all/themes/mbm/css/style.scss?qktcrf
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like the requested file cannot be found ("masked" HTTP 404) ..

And yes - there should no .scss file be requested at all.

Answer (score 0):

No, scss files cannot be used by the browser as css. Sounds like something is declaring that as an asset or mistakenly adding it via drupal_add_css.